# How to resize images with gwt and canvas?

Tags: html, gwt, canvas, image-resizing

is there a option to a animated resize with canvas in GWT? I use GWT 2.3.  and plugins like [GWTCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas)   doesn't work with this version.

Btw.: I haven't found any tutorial or example on how to use canvas in GWT. Maybe someone has a good convas tutorial for gwt?

greetz, destiny

Answer (score 1):

With GWT2.3 you don't need GWTCanvas, as the canvas support is present in GWT2.3.

Here are a few links
GWT's canvas Javadoc
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/index.html?com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/package-summary.html

Sample application
http://code.google.com/p/gwtcanvasdemo/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgwt%2Fgwtcanvasdemo%253Fstate%253Dclosed

A tutorial
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2338

There is no option to animate resize the image, you will have to implement your own function. To resize the image inside a canvas you need to use context.scale method, or context.drawImage(..) methods.